# Reduce/do.call to bind_rows in list of lists of data.frames

Tags: r, reshape

It has been hard for me expressing this in plain English, so if anyone can edit the language, that would be greatly appreciated.

I have a `list` object, where every element is a `list` of `data.frame` structures.

Some of these elements in the top level list might be empty, while the others have different numbers of data.frames (always an even number though).

My question (which seems suspiciously like the *opposite* of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400605/using-rapply-for-lists-of-lists-of-data-frames) one, is this:

How can I bind the rows of the data.frames in these lists so every element of the top-level list contains two data frames? These data.frames follow the same structure every time (I want to bind the rows of the data.frame number 1,3,5,7... and the data.frames number 2,4,6,8...

MRE as follows:

```
set.seed(1234)
listy <- list(`1` = list(),
              `2` = list(a = data.frame(a1 = runif(1:3), a2 = runif(1:3)),
                         b  = data.frame(a3 = runif(1:3), a4 = runif(1:3)),
                         c = data.frame(a1 = runif(1:3), a2 = runif(1:3)),
                         d = data.frame(a3 = runif(1:3), a4 = runif(1:3))))
```

`listy` is a list of 2 elements (`1`,`2`). Where `1` is empty. `2` is a list of `data.frames` (each with an even number of data.frames). I want to bind the rows of `2` so every element of the top level list has 2 data.frames (if they had data.frames in the first place).

My expected output is the following:

```
listb <- list(`1` = list(), 
          `2` = list(structure(list(a1 = c(0.113703411305323, 0.622299404814839, 0.609274732880294, 0.282733583590016, 0.923433484276757, 0.292315840255469), a2 = c(0.623379441676661, 0.860915383556858, 0.640310605289415, 0.837295628152788, 0.286223284667358, 0.266820780001581)), .Names = c("a1", "a2"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(a3 = c(0.0094957563560456, 0.232550506014377, 0.666083758231252, 0.186722789658234, 0.232225910527632, 0.316612454829738), a3.1 = c(0.514251141343266, 0.693591291783378, 0.544974835589528, 0.302693370729685, 0.159046002896503, 0.0399959180504084)), .Names = c("a3", "a3.1"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))))
```

Ideally, I would like to preserve `listy`, and its structure (the first element empty), the second one just with the bound rows. That is why I have tried the following, with no avail:

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(length(listy), function(i) {
  #skip empty lists
  if(length(listy[[i]]) < 1) {
    next
  } else {
    #make two lists
    #pairs list. even numbers
    listy[[i]][[1]] <- do.call(bind_rows, listy[[i]][seq(1,length(listy[[i]]), by = 1) %% 2 == 0])
    #pairs list. odd numbers
    listy[[i]][[2]] <- do.call(bind_rows, listy[[i]][seq(1,length(listy[[i]]), by = 1) %% 2 == 1])
  }
}) 


#another try, no positive result
lapply(length(listy), function(i) {
  #skip empty lists
  if(length(listy[[i]]) < 1) {
    next
  } else {
    #make two lists
    #pairs list. even numbers
    listy[[i]][[1]] <- Reduce(bind_rows, listy[[i]][seq(1,length(listy[[i]]), by = 1) %% 2 == 0])
    #pairs list. odd numbers
    listy[[i]][[2]] <- Reduce(bind_rows, listy[[i]][seq(1,length(listy[[i]]), by = 1) %% 2 == 1])
  }
})
```

Comment: Do you just want to rbind the dataframes together, or should something be done with the column names?

Comment: The column names should stay the same (they do when I try to bind them one by one). If my output in the MRE is wrong, please let me know so I can edit

Comment: In your listy[[2]], dataframe b has column names a3 and a3, while d has a4 and a4.

Comment: @Heroka I'll edit accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Assuming that column names match]. It's often easier to lapply over the list itself because it gets easier to manipulate, instead of indices. Here you go:

```
    listy2 <- lapply(listy, function(x){
      #get length
      current_length=length(x)
      if(current_length==0){
        res = x
      } else{
        res <- list(even=do.call(rbind,x[seq(2,current_length,by=2)]),
                    odd=do.call(rbind,x[seq(1,current_length,by=2)])
    )
        return(res)
      }
    }
    )


    > listy2
    $`1`
    list()

    $`2`
    $`2`$even
                 a3         a4
    b.1 0.009495756 0.51425114
    b.2 0.232550506 0.69359129
    b.3 0.666083758 0.54497484
    d.1 0.186722790 0.30269337
    d.2 0.232225911 0.15904600
    d.3 0.316612455 0.03999592

    $`2`$odd
               a1        a2
    a.1 0.1137034 0.6233794
    a.2 0.6222994 0.8609154
    a.3 0.6092747 0.6403106
    c.1 0.2827336 0.8372956
    c.2 0.9234335 0.2862233
    c.3 0.2923158 0.2668208


Edit with very much the same structure, but bind_rows to deal with more types inside the dataframe.

listy3 <- lapply(listy, function(x){ 
#get length 
current_length=length(x) 
if(current_length==0){ 
res = x 
} else{ 
res <- list(even=bind_rows(x[seq(2,current_length,by=2)]), 
odd=bind_rows(x[seq(1,current_length,by=2)]) 
# odd=do.call(bind_rows,x[seq(1,current_length,by=2)]) 
) 
return(res) 
} 
} 
)
```

Comment: Of course, 'rbind' should be easily replaced with 'bind_rows'

Comment: how coudl you extend this result for a list that is more than 2 items long? With the exact same structure (odds and pairs) and empty elements

Comment: I think it should work already for longer lists. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yeah, works great for lists of length 2. For other lists of longer (but similar structures), I get this error: ` Error in `[<-.ts`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(155.363636363636, 155.363636363636,  : only replacement of elements is allowed `.

Comment: Are you able to post some data? And we're talking about longer lists, with some empty elements and some elements containing multiple (but an even number) dataframes, right?

Comment: I tried it on my machine with a longer list (made up of randomly sampled listy[[1]] and listy[[2]]'s ) and got expected output without issues.

Comment: It's some sensitive data, and the results keep appearing in listy's of the same form with various lengths. Let me keep trying, if I can't figure something out I'll post a different question. Yeah the structure is the same, some empty lists, and some containing an even number of data.frames. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm curious if you manage to fix it yet; my solution was written with no constraints on the length of the original list --> makes me wonder what's going on.